# Java array concatenation using a comma?

Tags: java

I've got a bit of a puzzle I need help to unravel here and I've been unable to find the answer here thus far ITL.

In this file: https://bitcoinj.googlecode.com/git/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/core/PartialMerkleTree.java

Appears the line:
`byte[] left = recursiveExtractHashes(height-1, pos*2, used, matchedHashes).getBytes(), right;`

Which eclipse seems to think is valid Java and it compiles just fine..

So what exactly does the `", right"` portion perform?

I think its a declaration but I've never seen a declaration like this one.

Can anyone elaborate further?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This declaration is equivalent to something like this:

```
int i = 0, j;
```

`right` is declared but not initialized as an array of bytes, whereas `left` is both declared and initialized.

Comment: Not instantiated, merely declared. Instantiation will be when `new` is called.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Right. Vocab is getting rusty, haven't done a programming interview in a while. Fixing... (Thanks!)

Comment: Yes of course I see. I was distracted by the length and location of the assignment.

Comment: @Akumaburn Honestly, I think that code is poorly written for readability's sake. I would've left it as two separate lines. (Also, if you liked my answer, please accept it!) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Agreed about the readibility. It's good to be able to identify it, but I wouldn't emulate it if I were you.